# Problems with automatic login at a shell on a remote server to execute some commands

Tags: php, shell, command, remote-server

I want to achieve to login automatically on a shell with a specific user on a remote server and execute a command to install an android app.
I wrote some code to login into an remote server via `PHP`. I connected to the server with the method `ssh2_connect`, authenticate with an public key and it works. Now I want to install an apk file. I need to do the following commands

1. `sudo user`
2. `pm install -r /path/to/file/on/remote`

The user does not have a password. My script in `PHP` looks like

```
$con = ssh2_connect("xxx.xxx.xx.xxx", "xy", array("hostkey" => "ssh-rsa"));
if(ssh2_auth_pubkey_file($con, "user", $pubKey, $privKey, "password"))
{
    $dataToSend = file_get_contents($srcFile);
    if($dataToSend === false) throw new Exception("Could not open local file: " . $srcFile);
    if(fwrite( $sftpStream, $dataToSend) === false) throw new Exception("Could not send data from file: " . $srcFile);
    $shell = ssh2_shell($con, "xterm");
    fwrite($shell, "commands to login and install app");
    fclose($shell);
    echo "passed through!";
}
```

I did not find a solution which solved my problem. On my local pc it works with

```
echo shell_exec("echo <password> | sudo -S <command>");
```

In which way I have to modify the line above it will work on the remote server?

## EDIT:

If I write any commands and visit my website with some code like

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($con, "cd /path/to/anywhere; mkdir ./test; chmod 444 ./test/");
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
echo stream_get_contents($stream) . "<br />";
```

It works, the directory was created and the permission was set. But If I try to use something like `su whatever` I am still the same user and not like the example whatever.

The command `whoami` always returns the same user. Why works every command but not `su xxx`?

## SOLVED:

The remote server doesn't support the command `sudo` but I don't get any errpr and don't know he does not know command.

Any file like `sudoers` or anything else doesn't exists on the remote server like mentioned in the comments.

```
ssh2_exec($con, "su system pm install -r " . $dstFile . "&");
```

does everything I needed.

Comment: The issue _probably_ is that all such "password asking utilities" (`sudo` here) insist on an interactive tty and refuse to even ask for a password otherwise. This has obvious security reasons.

Comment: A possible solution could be to explicitly whitelist the `pm install` command for that user inside the `sudoers` file and mark it as executable _without_ password there.

Comment: @arkascha I edited my post at the end

Comment: Em, sorry, but did you even read what I explained what the issue and the possible solution is? You last comment suggest otherwise...

Comment: @arkascha Yeah I read your response and I'm working on it, thx for this advice. I only wanted to specify my problem for some other users who are reading this post ;). The remote server is working with android and it's not so easy to find the correct path where the file should stay